# xcode 4.2 ctrl-drag actions outlets

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I am following a very easy tutorial "My first iOS app" by apple on xcode 4.2 sdkiOS5.
According to the tutorial, I am supposed to ctrl-drag a button, a text field and a label into the implementation file. myviewcontroller.m (not the .h)
According to this tutorial and its images. in this myviewcontroller.m I am supposed to see

```
 #import "HelloWorldViewController.h"

 @interface HelloWorldViewController{}

 @end

 @implementation HelloWorldViewController
 ...
```

and supposed to drop from the view between the @interface and the @end.

The thing is that, from what I see in xcode, the @interface thing is not in myviewcontroller.m but in myviewcontroller.h

in myviewcontroller.m I can only see this:

```
 #import "HelloWorldViewController.h"

 @implementation HelloWorldViewController

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {....
```

When I try to drag buttons and text fields in myviewcontroller.m the popover doesn't allow me to change into "outlet", it's fixed on "action".

On the other hand, if I try to do the same in myviewcontroller.h, I can do whatever I want, the declaration corresponds to the images shown in the tutorial (that I drop between @interface ...
 (here)
@end )

but when I run the simulator, the screen stays black. Obviously, there is something wrong.

If anyone can help out a little, that would be awesome.

Cheers

Comment: Tutorial link will be appreciated.

Comment: Then just add it in at the top - it involves extending a class without subclassing it

Comment: Also, make sure you have embedded it in a uinavigation controller by selecting your view controller and then clicking embed at the top - otherwise I imagine it will be black

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be in the xib while dragging buttons and textfields?

Comment: Hi, first off, thanks for the answers. Here are links to the turtorial. [link]http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html  Section Create Outlets for the Text Field and the Label
Thanks for the help